# To automate file upload in oracle open script [OATS]

Tags: openscript

I am very new to Oracle Application Testing Suite(OATS).In my project I need to automate the file uploading functionality. That is , after clicking browse..button , file explorer will open.
My question is how to aytomate this scenario.

I serached many websites and in youtube but did not get any useful. Please help as it is important in my current project. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most of file upload based on windows objects .

Open Script doesn't support windows based object identification for that we have to use external plugin or jar files
best suitable one is RobotClass .

Here is the complete example 
http://www.testinghive.com/how-to-perform-file-upload-in-oats-tool/

```
try
{
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(200);
upload_parseChars("C:\\testDemo.xlsx", robot);
robot.delay(200);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
catch (AWTException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}



public void upload_parseChars(String letter, Robot robot) throws AbstractScriptException {
for (int i = 0; i < letter.length(); i++) {
//info("inside uf_Vik_parseChars method ");
char chary = letter.charAt(i);
//info("Current character = "+letter.charAt(i));
upld_typeCharacter(Character.toString(chary), robot);
}
}

public void upld_typeCharacter(String letter, Robot robot) throws AbstractScriptException {
// info("Pressed event ");
if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(letter.charAt(0))) {
try {
boolean upperCase = Character.isUpperCase(letter.charAt(0));
String variableName = "VK_" + letter.toUpperCase();
KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(new JTextField(), 0, 0, 0, 0, ' ');
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Class clazz = ke.getClass();
Field field = clazz.getField(variableName);
int keyCode = field.getInt(ke);
robot.delay(80);
if (upperCase)
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(keyCode);
robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
if (upperCase)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
} else {
if (letter.equals("!")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("@")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("#")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_3);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("#")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_3);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("$")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_4);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("%")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_5);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("^")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_6);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("&")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_7);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_7);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("*")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_8);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_8);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("=")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
} else if (letter.equals(" ")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
} else if (letter.equals("/")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
} else if (letter.equals("\\")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);
} else if (letter.equals("_")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals(":")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals(";")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
} else if (letter.equals(",")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
} else if (letter.equals("-")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals("?")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
} else if (letter.equals(" ")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
} else if (letter.equals(".")) {
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
}

}
}
```

Comment: do we have any official document saying that OATS does not support window based actions.If yes, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

THE download dialog and upload dialog is  supported.  try to record one and try related